# Have you ever used a non-binary semaphore to solve an non-academic task?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

This may be silly, but I'm looking for so-called 'real life' examples of software which uses a semaphore with a count or more than 1.

In other words, no bouncers, librarians or toilet examples please.

Comment: And why is this exactly? Even people who don't have an example might be able to help you if you just tell us why you need this? What are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Nanne I think it is quite clear from my question that I not trying to solve a problem. I just want to satisfy my curiosity.

Comment: I think it is quite clear from my comment that it wasn't quite clear, otherwise I wouldn't have asked it, now would I? A simple "nothing, just curious" would have sufficed as an answer, but instead you choose to be condescending. Good for you, have fun with your question.

Comment: @Nanne I wasn't being difficult. I genuinely thought (and still do) my question is clear. Relax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've used something like this for a "read/write" lock. That is, I want to allow up to N simultaneous readers, and only one writer at a time when there are no active readers.

So any reading thread locks the semaphore and increases the read count. If the read count is smaller than N the lock succeeds and the reader may continue. If not, the lock causes the reader thread to sched_yield.

If I want to lock for writing, I set the count to N so that no more readers can lock - e.g. they all start sleeping when they try locking. The writer thread keeps trying to lock the read semaphore. Every time a reader releases, the writer increments N again, until there are no more readers.

Then the write lock succeeds, the write operation happens, and the read semaphore is set back to zero so that reader threads may continue.

Answer (score 1):

Semaphores with endless count (LONG_MAX in Win32) are used to implement sender-consumer scheme. Such semaphore is created with max. count = LONG_MAX (0xFFFFFF...). Sender (resource creator) creates some resource and releases the semaphore. Receiver (resource consumer) waits for this semaphore, waking up exactly once when the sender releases this semaphore.
Regarding other values more than 1, I have never used them.